# Many same extruded windows

Tags: modeling, mesh, extrude

So I am looking for a way to extrude many similar windows in a wall. They should be exact size and stay on same distance from each other. How would you do that? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Best to use an array, and keep it live (unapplied) as long as possible, in case you decide you need change the window in any way..

Answer (score 1):

As Lukasz-40sth said, you could use the *Array* modifier:

- Create a plane, subdivide it.
- Extrude your window.
- Use 2 *Array* modifiers to repeat your object horizontally and vertically.
- Work your window as much as you want until you're satisfied.
- You can either keep or apply your modifiers.
- If you want to apply, enable the *Merge* option of the modifier so that the adjacent vertices of your new object merge. If you didn't enable it, go in *Edit* mode, select all and *Remove Doubles* with <kbd>W</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: oh yes you're right

Answer (score 0):

Add a plane for the wall. Next, add another for the window. Use Array modifier twice on the window plane, followed by Knife Project .  Remove selected faces and extrude the result.